# Talend Job not letting me map tMap to another tMap Component

Tags: etl, talend

I have created a job in Talend as follows :-
[image]

I wish to map tMap_2 and tMap_3 to tMap_4, but for some reason it just isnt letting me. tMap_2 and _3 show warning messages stating 'This component does not have enough "Row" type outputs'. But For each of these I have already created an output. I am pretty certain what I am trying to achieve is possible in Talend, and googling about this hasnt turned up anything significant. So could some one please advise why it's not letting me join the tMaps 2 and 3 to 4?
P.S. Kindly let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: You cannot connect components making a loop, and be sure that you can achieve your goal without looping components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent looped components connection in a job, you can use the tHashOutput and tHashInput to store the data of a flow and read it later, by default those components are hidden, you can install them from the menu "file" -> "edit project settings" -> "designer" -> "palette setting"

[image]

Comment: Is it that in Talend no circular formations in flows are allowed?

Comment: @Sparky Yes, thats what im trying to say

Comment: @Sparky Im happy for that :)